# Running jquery from inside modal

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to run jquery from inside my modal window, but it doesn't seem to be doing anything. Here is my jquery:

`$('select').on('change', function() { alert( this.value ); })`

The code should alert the browser what a dropdown was changed to when it changes.

My dropdowns are generated based on results from an sql table like so

```
<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon1"><?=$value[1];?></span>
    <select id="myChange" name="goneTeammates[<?=$uniqueLoop;?>]" class="myChange form-control">
        <option class="white" value="">Attended</option>
        <option class="red" value="<?=$value[0];?>|A">Absent</option>
        <option class="blue" value="<?=$value[0];?>|V">Vacation/Holiday</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

I'm not sure why I can't get this very simple thing to run, it shouldn't be this difficult.

P.S I know that jQuery is running, because the dropdowns are visible in a modal window that works properly.

I get no errors on console.

Comment: Is the modal coming from a template somewhere or is it already on the page? It's possible the select doesn't exist for the $('select') to wire up.

Comment: @Zach it exists on the same page. In fact, it exists right under where the load function for the modal is which I know is working obviously.

Comment: For sanity sake - go ahead and change the selector to $('#myChange') and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @Zach I had switched it from that trying many different things. Turns out you were correct though, Jumpdarts code worked.

Comment: His works because he's wiring up the change event on the document.  It's not very efficient, but it'll filter all change events that bubble up to those that originate from a select element.

Comment: What's the most efficient way?

Comment: There's a couple options - you add the event when the modal is added to the DOM, or you put the event handler on the first parent of the modal (this might be the document because modals are usually appended to the end). This is the reason live() was deprecated from jquery.

Comment: probably append the handler in the html or catch and handle it at a higher level that you know exists instead of at the document

Comment: yeah what @zach said

Answer (score 1):

the elements do not exist yet when this line gets executed

try

```
   $( document ).on('change', 'select', function(){
       alert ( this.value );
   });
```

and if you are going to just throw it on the document or something like that, try and use a more specific class for the selector and clear the event before you ass them. This prevents you duplicating the handler and end up with crazy stuff happening if that code gets executed more than once. Would look something like the following:

```
   $( document ).off('change', '.myCoolSelect');
   $( document ).on('change', '.myCoolSelect', function(){
       alert ( this.value );
   });
```

But you dont have to use document. Any parent node that you know will exist you can add the handlers.

Comment: That worked. Thank you. Could you please explain a bit what this actually does, as I've never seen it used that way before.

Comment: its kind of like Zach said above. When your line executes, the element is not in the dom. You probably append it to the dom later via whatever modal thingy you are using